# How to add checkbox inside the grid in GridMvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I need check box inside the fields `Module_view`, `Module_Edit` and `Module_delete`. I am using `GRIDMVC`, can anyone tell me how to add check box inside `GRIDMVC`?

Here is my code

```cs
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
    {

        columns.Add()
                .Encoded(false)
                .Sanitized(false)
                .SetWidth(30)
                .RenderValueAs(d =>
                    @<b>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = d.PK_Module_Id })

                    </b>);

        columns.Add(c => c.tblMaster_ModuleName.ModuleName).Titled("Module Name");
        columns.Add(c => c.tblMaster_ClientOrganizationDetails.Organization_Code).Titled("Organization Code").Filterable(true);
        columns.Add(c => c.Module_View).Titled("View");

        columns.Add(c => c.Module_Edit).Titled("Edit");
        columns.Add(c => c.Module_Delete).Titled("Delete");


    }).Sortable().Filterable().WithMultipleFilters()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [documentation](https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Render%20button%2C%20checkbox%20etc%20in%20the%20grid%20cell) I would like to suggest this answer.

```
columns.Add(c=>Module_view).Titled("View").Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).SetWidth(30).RenderValueAs(c => Html.CheckBox("checked", false));
columns.Add(c=>c.Module_Delete).Titled("Delete").Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).SetWidth(30).RenderValueAs(o => Html.CheckBox("checked", false));
columns.Add(c=>Module_Edit).Titled("Edit").Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).SetWidth(30).RenderValueAs(o => Html.CheckBox("checked", false));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).SetWidth(30).RenderValueAs(d => @<input type="checkbox"id="chk_@d.PK_Module_Id" style="max-width: 26px; max-height: 26px;">);
```